# How to improve Google Recaptchav3 score as it returns 0.1 for genuine users

Tags: python, google-chrome, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

Recaptchav3 score is random for a set of users

It returns 0.1 as score for logged in Safari browser request
0.3 for firefox and chrome

Any suggestions to improve the score as the recommended threshold is 0.5

```
    request = recaptchaenterprise_v1.CreateAssessmentRequest()
    request.assessment = assessment
    request.parent = project_name

    response = client.create_assessment(request)
```